# My-weather-indicator error or bug?

Tags: 18.04, my-weather-indicator

It still worked yesterday, it won't start this morning and it's set to start automatically. In fact, if I run it separately, it won't move. It is marked as installed in synaptic. I do not know what to do? Version 0.9.5-0extras20.04.09 is installed ...
Please help!

Comment: My system booted yesterday without MWI started. But today it launched normally. I use Ubuntu MATE 18.04 with MWI 0.9.5-0extras20.04.09 . I suppose that it is networking issue. Have you tried to run it manually by `/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/my-weather-indicator/bin/my-weather-indicator` ?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue, with the same behavior described by *NOrbert*.
But, in " https://github.com/atareao/my-weather-indicator/issues/85 ", I found the right solution and now it works.

Bye,
Piero

the complete text of solution:

---

***jochen-st commented 19 days ago
The fix is already contained in 4bfc87d.***

You could download the file

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/atareao/my-weather-indicator/master/src/wopenweathermapapi.py

and store it in

/opt/extras.ubuntu.com/my-weather-indicator/share/my-weather-indicator/wopenweathermapapi.py"

or edit the file manually to add

CONDITION[616] = 'rain and snow'

in the appropriate place.

---